# NoClassDefFoundError for io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator

Tags: java, docker, gradle, cassandra, intellij-14

I have created a Cassandra Client written with Achilles Object mapping in java (using IntelliJ + Gradle). My Client works fine locally in IntelliJ, but throws the exception when deployed in a docker container. I am currently stuck with the below exception in my docker container.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator    at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.NettyOptions.afterBootstrapInitialized(NettyOptions.java:144)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.newBootstrap(Connection.java:903)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.access$100(Connection.java:751)
>     at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initAsync(Connection.java:139)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:807)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:252)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:201)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1631)
>     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1549)
>     at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:160)  at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:342)   at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:317)   at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:259)    at
>   java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)   at
>   info.archinnov.achilles.configuration.ArgumentExtractor.initSession(ArgumentExtractor.java:186)
>     at
>   info.archinnov.achilles.configuration.ArgumentExtractor.initConfigContext(ArgumentExtractor.java:96)
>     at
>   info.archinnov.achilles.bootstrap.AbstractManagerFactoryBuilder.buildConfigContext(AbstractManagerFactoryBuilder.java:60)
>     at
>   info.archinnov.achilles.generated.ManagerFactoryBuilder.build(ManagerFactoryBuilder.java:38)
>     at
>   com.ds.db.cassandra.AchillesClient.(AchillesClient.java:22)
>     at
>   com.ds.message.RabbitMQMsgClient$1.open(RabbitMQMsgClient.java:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)

But the class, `io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator` which is part of 
`netty-buffer-4.0.56.Final.jar` is already part of the classpath.

When I tried testing thing locally from my Intellij IDE, things are working fine.
But after deployment, I am facing this issue in my docker container.

The service is started in my docker container like this:

> java -server
>   -XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/ds/srv/diagnostics/msgreader-1589749851-2s89z.heapdump
>   -Xmx614m -Xms614m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=126M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:CICompilerCount=4 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=60 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dapp.dir=/opt/ds/sw/apps/msgreader -Dserver.name=msgreader -Dlog.dir=/opt/ds/var/log/msgreader **-cp /opt/ds/sw/apps/javacontainer/resources:/opt/ds/sw/apps/msgreader/lib/*:/opt/ds/sw/apps/msgreader/resources:/opt/ds/sw/apps/javacontainer/lib/***
>   com.ds.msg.Server start

From the above cmd, you can notice the **-cp** argument mentioning the class path. And this path contains `netty-buffer-4.0.56.Final.jar`.

I later found that `netty-all-4.0.51.Final.jar` is also part of the class path and this jar also contains the same class file. I even tried removing jars, with all possible combination. But still I am facing the same issue.

Even in case of multiple versions of a jar file, we should be getting **NoSuchMethodError**, Can anyone please help me understand the problem.

Comment: And how is IntelliJ executing this service - the command should be in the first line of the output in the 'run' window?

Comment: I am not starting the server locally, I instantiated the client in a test class, in the same package and ran it

Comment: There should still be a command displayed at the top of the `Run` window, which contains the classpath used by IntelliJ.

Comment: @KonradBotor it points to gradle cache, which has both the jar files

Comment: Hmm, you could try listing all jars in the classpath, for example by adding this class: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/ to your project and then in Docker running it instead of com.ds.msg.Server class. Also could you post your Dockerfile and project structure?

Comment: hmm.. thanks, will try it..I can't post dockerfile as the docker images are autogenerated over a framework

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173752/discussion-between-deepak-and-konrad-botor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the answer, the issue is what I guessed in my question. Multiple versions of same jar, had caused the failure. To find it, I used the following in my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'project-report'
```

And ran,

```
gradle htmlDependencyReport
```

It will give us a good HTML report on the dependencies Tree. We can even use the below cmd, but it will tough to follow up in a multi module gradle projects

```
gradle dependencies
```

In the HTML report, I found **achilles-core** module had dependency on `netty-buffer-4.0.56.Final.jar` and another module had dependency on `netty-all-4.0.51.Final.jar`.
So when I tried the following for achilles in **build.gradle**, things were working fine:

> ```
> compile(group:'info.archinnov', name: 'achilles-core', version: '6.0.0'){
>     exclude module: 'netty-buffer'
> }
> ```

As `netty-all-4.0.51.Final.jar` already had the classes required for achilles Object mapping, my project started working on deployment.

**Another reason for Failure, even after removing the duplicate jars files from the docker container:**
(Hard)Restarting the pod, in turn created a new pod, which pulls the same Dockerimage from docker repo.

IntelliJ some how, resolves the PATH issue, when running locally :/

Comment: Sounds interesting, good to know that NoClassDefFoundError, also arises due to multiple versions of same jar

Comment: it is always better to use project-report in gradle, as once your project grows, it will be difficult to maintain the dependencies..